# For LOOP jQuery total width of my slides

Tags: jquery

I'm new in jquery and I'm trying to make a slider likes this http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/lazyLoad.html but with different size images. I must to use FOR LOOP and I made this:

```
$(document).ready(function) {

var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;

var i;

for (i = 0; i < widthTot; i++) {
    var widthTot= widthTot + $('#slider ul li:eq('+i+')').width();
}

});
```

where is the mistake? 
thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function) {
    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var i;
    var widthTot=0;

    for (i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) { // Use slideCount instead of widthTot
        widthTot= widthTot + $('#slider ul li:eq('+i+')').width();
    }
});
```

Comment: WC... You can rate my answer and mark as correct answer here :)

Comment: $(window).load(function() {

var slideCount = $('.slider ul li').length;

var i;

var widthTot = 0;

for (i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) {

widthTot += $('#container .slider ul li:eq('+i+')').width();
}

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //                     ^
    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;

    var widthTot = 0;
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    for (var i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) {
    //                  ^^^^^^^^^^
        widthTot += $('#slider ul li:eq(' + i + ')').width();
        // ^^^^^^ Remove var
    }
    alert(widthTot);
});
```

1. You missed the `(` of `ready` function
2. Declare the `widthTot` outside of the `for` loop
3. Remove `var` of `widthTot` inside `for` loop
4. Use `slideCount` inside `for` condition

Answer (score -1):

Now the question is: How can I put all my images inline without go ahead?

```
$(window).load(function() {

  var slideCount = $('.slider ul li').length;
  var i;
  var widthTot = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) {
    widthTot += $('#container .slider ul li:eq('+i+')').width();
  }

  $('.slider').css('width', widthTot);

  $( '.slider ul li' ).clone().appendTo( '.slider ul');

  $('.slider ul').addClass('.original')

});
```

because If I use the clone, the images go ahed, but I want that the clone stay in the same line with the other img!